# How to fix "Type 'K extends X[T] ? keyof K : never' cannot be used to index type" for nested object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a function where the first parameter (data) is an array of type Product, the second (element) is any property inside Product and the third and fourth parameters are properties of "element".
So let's say "Product" has the property "Customer", I want to get "Id" and "Name" out of Customer.

I have the following code

```js
function getFilterItem<T extends keyof Product, K extends Product[T]>(
  data: Product[],
  element: T,
  id: K extends Product[T] ? keyof K : never,
  name: K extends Product[T] ? keyof K : never,
): FilterItem[] {
  // removed for simplicity
}
```

What I want is to be able to call it like so

```js
getFilterItem(data, 'customer', 'id', 'name');
```

With the code above, it identifies correctly the parameters, so if I pass a property that doesn't exist in 'customer' it'll tell me it's wrong. My problem is when I try to get the property it'll say "Type 'K extends Product[T] ? keyof K : never' cannot be used to index type".

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but I imagine it's complaining because Product[T] could be any type in Product, let's say "Product" has the property "price" which is a number, so using something like `getFilterItem(data, 'price', 'id', 'name');` typescript wouldn't be able to index it using the third and fourth parameter.

This is the full code (I've removed some logic to make it simpler)

```js
function getFilterItem<T extends keyof Product, K extends Product[T]>(
  data: Product[],
  element: T,
  id: K extends Product[T] ? keyof K : never,
  name: K extends Product[T] ? keyof K : never,
): FilterItem[] {
  data.forEach((product) => {
    const value = product[element];
    if (value) {
      const valueId = value[id]; // here the eror is shown
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make it accept 'id' as a key of 'Product[T]'?

Here is a working example where I want to get "id" and "autonomyLevel" from a property inside Product:

[sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCwAqAngA4oDeAsAFDLLBYBcyIOAtgEbQDcNdYpCMwDOYKKADmvagF8aNUJFiIUAQRxgMIDGyIAZCADcIAG2RVa9Ji3Zco0unA1ad+o6ZFjJ0udQXhoeCRkAEkQXFEoInM+K2ZWTh5Y0AixIk9xECkaX38lIJR0bDwwAGUwODAcYRjLBnjbJMtRSuqM7xz5akVAlWQ9YBgIAGEiBBMKZOsEuwdkE0GRsYn2rJ8unuVgotx8Wrp6m0T7ZLY4CSFkSI7LATIAfmYdkuIyOadNbV0DYxNH5HUn1cP1McxaVWE-2e+HKrWEcxS1S8EGEzDCqSiAG0ALpzBZDUbjFHMAYE5YQHHrPzUGA4ED4YBaZAXMAAMWAJiUIUgbAAPARkBAAB6QcI1ADWECIGBgaEwuzAAD4ABSxLCVOBPeUlHEAGlipggbAg4GYBH1dWskulsuhYExBGxFroIDgxuY1plcuK+AdTpoAEp9sh1RUAHQwDBQACiiAAFsrlSRtfggwBeRXBugILSiZCGOAmHAoNPIZM++2G43gXGxA6y5UFosQIMWOjt5A5kB5pvFkJYZCl3sUhi1yx0XwTgOdalYCDjOBQFBdvOhzXehU0FnsznQblG5WYtdO5AAcg+Lm+7hMp91Z4Yt7PF6+bl+p4D0iAA)

Comment: Please provide an [mre]. There's too much guesswork involved filling in the missing pieces.

Comment: You don't need `K extends Product[T]`. That's redundant because `K` is already constrained to `Product[T]`. Simply type `id` and `name` as `keyof K`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you right, you have something like:

```
interface Product {
  customer: Customer
}

interface Customer {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

And you want the third and fourth arguments to the keys of object you would get by accessing the first argument by the second argument.

```
declare const data: Product
getFilterItem([data], 'customer', 'id', 'name');
```

---

Then you only need one generic type parameter, the `"customer"` key. The `id` and `name` keys can be inferred from that.

```
function getFilterItem<T extends keyof Product>(
  data: Product[],
  element: T,
  id: keyof Product[T],
  name: keyof Product[T],
) {
  data.forEach((product) => {
    const value = product[element];
    if (value) {
      const valueId = value[id]; // works
    }
  })
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCzIDeAsAFDLII4DOYGAttAFzIDCNdjUZAvmWaEixEKdrQbQiZCgAdMMgHI56LEMoBG0acjkYZAZTBQWtKKADmvfqRg4Q+YBhDJzEMADFgAGyEBJSPQAPAAqyBAAHpAgWNTIANYQAJ4YMGiYuPgAfAAU2lhwYHAs6Nh4YADaALoANNoQXhCM4CzBteTIwFgsCcmpJRkVwTXaIHCM3UkpaaX45UNtAJRS7fmFAHQwGFAAoogAFtnZugNLALyZyxQUCE60yABucF44KKc66WXl9Y0Q4JUA3NoKMBUtlHs8IEsSO0rpRbgRwS9fFhkG9ERByp0AUDkHx2jwFlZSGQsBAEF44FAUDcQHdVkVpgMyK4PN4-AFsuV6TVkAByKjiLi86p83SKZTC0XyQxQXkLQGkFmeHzQfyNTnckX8jgSWVauCS3nqOX-ZAAejNYSgmCgyDgsQiMjJkCwZCAA)

---

> The properties may be null

In that case you my solution gives you `never` for the secondary keys because the type of `Product[T]` is something like `AutonomyLevel | never`. And the `keyof` that is `never` because both types in that union share no keys in common.

But if you `Exclude` undefined from the type you are getting the `keyof` then it works:

```
function getFilterItem<T extends keyof Product>(
  data: Product[],
  element: T,
  id: keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>,
  name: keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>,
) {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCwAqAngA4oDeAsAFDLLBYBcyIOAtgEbQDcNdYpCMwDOYKKADmvagF8aNUJFiIUAQRxgMIDGyIAZCADcIAG2RVa9Ji3Zco0unA1ad+o6ZFjJ0udQXhoeCRkAEkQXFEoInM+K2ZWTh5Y0AixIk9xECkaX38lIJR0bDwwAGUwODAcYRjLBnjbJMtRSuqM7xz5akVAlWQ9YBgIAGEiBBMKZOsEuwdkE0GRsYn2rJ8unuVgotx8Wrp6m0T7ZLY4CSFkSI7LATIAfmYdkuIyOadNbV0DYxNH5HUn1cP1McxaVWE-2e+HKrWEcxS1S8EGEzDCqSiAG0ALpzBZDUbjFHMAYE5YQHHrPzUGA4ED4YBaZAXMAAMWAJiUIUgbAAPARkBAAB6QcI1ADWECIGBgaEwuzAAD4ABSxLCVOBPeUlHEAGlipggbAg4GYBH1dWskulsoAokLxjgsBBedCwJiCNjdcg6c6YKAIFhFRa6CA4MbmNaZch7Y7na7tfgPV6feEIP6QIHgzQAJT7ZDqioAOhgGCgtsQAAtlcqSImwHmALyK-N0BBaUTIQxwEw4FCN5B14pJw3G8C42IHWXK7u9iB5ix0JfIdsgTuzvshLDIAcbikMCeWOi+Y85zrU53jOBQFCrzuFzVy4dgGgs9mc6Dco3KzEPlMAcg+FxvncEx-29f8GHA5BAOcL43F+f8c2kIA)

---

However, this presents a new problem:

```
function getFilterItem<T extends keyof Product>(
  data: Product[],
  element: T,
  id: keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>,
  name: keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>,
) {
  data.forEach((product) => {
    const value = product[element];
    if (value) {
      const valueId = value[id];
      // Type 'keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>' cannot be used to index type 'string | number | ProductType | AutonomyLevel | ProductStatus | Industry[] | LifeCycle[]'.(2536)
    }
  })
}
```

The typescript compiler can have a hard time matching up differently derived generic types. In this case we've done the work to make this type safe, but Typescript doesn't believe us.

Honestly, and I very very rarely recommend this, I might add a little runtime check and then mark it as an expected error:

```
  data.forEach((product) => {
    const value = product[element];
    if (value && id in value) {
      // @ts-expect-error The compiler has a hard time understanding
      // that `id` is guaranteed to be a valid key of `value`.
      const valueId: Product[T] = value[id];
    }
  })
```

I find this solution acceptable because:

1. It's entirely internal to the function and therefore does not affect the overall types of your program.
2. It has the correct runtime checks to ensure that `id` is indeed a key in the `value` object.

It's unfortunate to unfortunate to disable the type checker in this case, and I'm open to other ways to eliminate it, but in this case, I this it's reasonably safe-ish.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and clarifications, I'm sorry I haven't provided enough info about it. You were right except the properties may be null, I have just edited the question to provide a playground link where the error happens, you may see it here: [Sandbox](https://shorturl.at/ovN89)

Comment: That makes things trickier for sure. See my updated answer.

Comment: wouldn't this be a typescript bug/lacking feature?

Answer (score 1):

Notice also that if what you want is the array element `id` value as the code suggests, you would not need to provide the prop name as an argument to the function as in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2#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). For that, `T` would be the common props for all the types shared in `Product` keys, and not the keys themselves in the case more that one was shared, for the provided code only seems to be the `id`.

One point I'd like to make is that in case its  not clear if typescript's behaviour makes sense I'd like to provide this explanation.
The `id: keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>` enables you to call the `getFilterItem` with the `'id'` argument. You'd need this as long there are optional arguments in the `Product` type.

Taken that into account, notice the core of the problem is that what is being trying to be done is get the index of a type `Product[T]` with the type `keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>`. Which are different types (meaning the index, `T` is a different type from `keyof Exclude<Product[T], undefined>)`, as one may hold undefineds due to optional arguments and the other may not. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCwAqAngA4oDeAsAFDLLBYBcyIOAtgEbQDcNdYpCMwDOYKKADmvagF8aNUJFiIUAQRxgMIDGyIAZCADcIAG2RVa9Ji3Zco0unA1ad+o6ZFjJ0udQXhoeCRkAEkQXFEoInM+K2ZWTh5Y0AixIk9xECkaX38lIJR0bDwwAGUwODAcYRjLBnjbJMtRSuqM7xz5akVAlWQ9YBgIAGEiBBMKZOsEuwdkE0GRsYn2rJ8unuVgotx8WroAegO4m0T7WKP6NjgJIWRIjssBMmYdkuIyOadNbV0DYxMzHUP1c-1McxaVWEr0wuzKFShcxS1S8EGhoXCKKiAG0ALpzBZDUbjNHMAZE5YQPHrPzUGA4ED4YBaZC3MAAMWAJiUIUgbAAPARkBAAB6QcI1ADWECIGBgaFhJQAfAAKWJYSpwGHFfB4gA0sVMEDYEHAzAIBrq1mlsvlAFEReMcFgIPy3rqCLi9cgGS6YKAIFglZa6CA4CbmDa5cgHU6XW7FR6vT7whB-SBA8GaABKfbIDUVAB0MAwUDtiAAFiqVSRE2BcwBeJV5ugILSiZCGOAmHAoBvIWs6sDYo0m8D42J0QbIFVdnsQXMWOjL5BtkAdue9kJYZD9zdUhgTyx0Xwn7OdWku8ZwKAoNcdgtahVDmhsznc6C840q7GP5MAcm+Fw-ncEx-29f8GHA5BAOcX43ABf9s2kIA). Removed the id and the image becase due to the [keyof
and Lookup Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) you are are also narrowing down your type fit to `string | number`, into whom `id` would never fit in.

For me the error makes sense because regarding type safety should not be allowed to exclude `undefined` for the `id` argument in `getFilterItem`, and then allowing it back for the index check of `Product[T]` with T holding undefineds as there are optional arguments.

Another thing I'd like to mention is that I think due to [keyof
and Lookup Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) there might be different behaviours accessing props with `object.prop` and `object.[prop]`

Check what I mean in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCwAqAngA4oDeAsAFDLLBYBcyIOAtgEbQDcNdYpCMwDOYKKADmvagF8aNUJFiIUAQRxgMIDGyIAZCADcIAG2RVa9Ji3Zco0unA1ad+o6ZFjJ0udQXhoeCRkAEkQXFEoInM+K2ZWTh5Y0AixIk9xECkaX38lIJR0bDwwAGUwODAcYRjLBnjbJMtRSuqM7xz5akVAlWQ9YBgIAGEiBBMKZOsEuwdkE0GRsYn2rJ8unuVgotx8Wv5BAH5mHZLiMjmnTW1dA2MTY+R1a9c70zmWquFH0-xy1uEcxS1S8EGEzDCqSicwWQ1G4zBzAGcOWEHWfmoMBwIHwwC0yAkEDAADFgCYlCFIGwADwEZAQAAekHCNQA1hAiBgYGhMLswAA+AAUsSwlTgJ15JQA2gBdAA0sVMEDYEHAzAICrq1nZnO5AFEGeMcFgINTfmApQR5chsSaYKAIFh+Zq6CA4CrmDqucgDUaTWbJfhLdbbRB7SBHc6aABKfbIUUVAB0MAwUD1iAAFoLBSRA2BYwBeflxugILSiZCGOAmHAoAvIXPFINKlXgGVzOiDZCCqs1iCxix0IfIMsgCu92shLDIesTiCJhgd5C+OgyaOdDEm8ZwKAoUcVhPinlNsA0QkkskUqmCqWH60AciuLlu7hM97lyHvDHfn6fNzc9z3tG0hAA). Where `value.id` works/compiles but `value[id]` does not.

So there are 2 things that would need to be fixed here regarding the type definition
1.- If undefined/optional args are allowed
2.- Handle the property access